How to make UWP MediaPlayer to be loop mode when casting to a TV?
I find that when using UWP MediaPlayer, it works well to be in loop mode when set as below:
player.IsLoopingEnabled = true;
player.AutoPlay = true;

But when casting the source to a smart TV (DLNA), then the loop mode doesn't work at all.
private CastingConnection connection;


//Create a new casting connection to the device that's been selected
connection = ((CastingDevice)castingDevicesList.SelectedItem).CreateCastingConnection();

//Register for events
connection.ErrorOccurred += Connection_ErrorOccurred;
connection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;

//Cast the loaded video to the selected casting device.
CastingConnectionErrorStatus status = await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(player?.GetAsCastingSource());

Any advise?
